# Images are showing up as red x's on IE, shows up fine in other browsers

Tags: image, internet-explorer-8

Using IE8, when I view one of our webpages, some of the images aren't showing up and just show red X's with the alt text. The same page (copied the url) works just fine in Chrome and Firefox. Other users are experiencing this problem as well.

The thing is, when I initially viewed the page after someone let me know there was a problem, the images loaded fine, but a few minutes later they experienced the problem. If I view just the image as mysite/image.jpg it shows the red x as well and if I copy that url it loads fine in other browsers.

Also, if I save the image from Chrome to my desktop and try to open it in IE, I get a red X.

code (note: there are no spaces after the start of the tag,s I inserted them here so they would show up)

```
< a href="mysite/posters/view/4702838/">
    < img src="mysite/art/img/art_print_thumb/d142be1d2b72e676b731c09b67290c89.jpg" border="0" alt="All Because Two Peop...<span>All Because Two People Fell In Love</span>" />
    < /a>
```

Comment: could you post the html, for example ?

Comment: I can, but this happens even if I just open the image in the browser from my desktop.

Comment: try to see the image properties from some program, like irfanview. I'd bet there's something weird / wrong with it's color space that IE can't hand properly.

Comment: It seems as though those images were using the CKYK profile instead of RGB.

Comment: :) java have / had some problems with these images too

Comment: want me to add this as an answer, so you will accept, or will you add one yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though those images were using the CKYK profile instead of RGB.