# gif image file displays red "x" on IE

Tags: asp.net, transparency, bing-maps, gif, system.drawing

To start off, I have searched google & SO ([Images are showing up as red x's on IE, shows up fine in other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7193350/72324)), tried out the suggestions, but they did not resolve my issue.

I am trying to create a transparent image by following the code shown at: [How do you Draw Transparent Image using System.Drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189392/72324). I am using a 3rd party mapping control "[Simplovation](https://simplovation.com/default.aspx)"

However, this is what I get when I run my webpage:
[image]

How can I get the actual image to appear?
I tried converting to RGB, but no luck.

Based on the code in "[How do you Draw Transparent Image using System.Drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189392/72324)" the actual image should appear like:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your url path to the image is correct?  The red x means IE can't find the file.

Comment: yes, url path is correct

Comment: Just to be sure: Would you mind posting the rendered url?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell: theImage.Image = "../images/Pushpins/ATestImage1.gif";

Comment: I meant the **rendered** url or even better the HTML code where you reference the image.

Answer (score 0):

IE is very specific about the image type and actual image content. In other words, IE cannot display if image type and content doesn't match.

For example, renaming just file extension - bmp to gif - doesn't work in IE, although it is not an issue in other browser.

Easiest way to check is to browse that page in other browser. If you can see image in other browser, you can make sure that image format is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a long list of potential problems here, let's address 3 of them:

- Permissions
  You imply that you are creating this image from code. How are you doing that? If the IIs worker process, running in the user context of the application pool account, is creating this image, does it create/save it to a location that is accesible anonymously? (or whatever your authentication model is)
- File locked?
  Again, since you are implying your are creating the image from code, to you close the file handle properly?
- Path.
  You say that the image Url is correct, but are you really 100% sure? Press F12 on IE and use the developer tools to determine if you get any type of HTTP error when IE is trying to request the image.